# How to get zone-id from interface index for send with ipv6 addr?

Tags: ipv6, getaddrinfo

I have to get zone id from network interface index for send data with ipv6 addr.

Normally interface index number or interface name is used for zone id with ipv6 addr.

But someone told me interface name or index number is not zone id.

so... is there someone know how to get correct zone id from ifindex?

my system is linux/android/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope-id is actually the interface index number, so you can use that.